# My Ubuntu did'nt update properly

Tags: 22.04, 23.04

I was using ubuntu 22.04 and wanted to update to the newest version available (23.04). I updated using the software updater but it looks like just my gnome was update from gnome 42 to gnome 44 (it even has the lunar lobster wallpapers). When I run cat /etc/os-release its shows that I'm still on ubuntu 22.04. What happened?
ps: Software updater still sat that I have a new version available to upgrade but it doesn't do anything
att: I discovered that when I run apt upgrade some packages was being held back, so I run sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade  and it worked

Comment: You have reboot after your *release-upgrade*?  as the system will reload the version details unless processes restart.  *Note: the release comes from the package `base-files` so I'd explore & provide details as to what package version you have installed; it should upgrade correctly - but I've seen a number of users report as you have; for best results upgrade via every release; ie. 22.04 to 22.10 then 23.04*

Comment: I have reboot after the install, but I'll try to update to 22.10 then to 23.04.